# vb6 with inno setup... help me please

Tags: vb6, inno-setup

I created a software that is associated with the processing of payments and purchases of pulses.
I have used VB6, sqlite2009 for Inno to create the database and its set-up. I created a program called 'IZ'
story short, if a user installs my program in the registry window will then make a folder in called "PCclient".
the problem is: when the user will uninstall the program that I created (IZ) Registry files (PCclient) can not be lost.
What should I do so when the user will uninstall the program, the registry files (PCclient) are also be deleted.
what script should I add to the registry file 'PCclient' erased at the time of uninstall.
do I have to add the script in VB6 or in the Inno? and what script should I add?

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

user404222 to avoid the delete of you registry entry when the application is uninstalled you should remove the flag `uninsdeletevalue`

check this sample

This value is deleted when the uninstaller is executed

```
[Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: SOFTWARE\MyKey; ValueType: string; ValueName: InstallDir; ValueData:MyData; Flags: uninsdeletevalue
```

In this case the key is not deleted.

```
[Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: SOFTWARE\MyKey; ValueType: string; ValueName: InstallDir; ValueData:MyData
```

Comment: thank's.....

I will delete the files when uninstalling the files 'PCclient'
location of the files 'pcclient' is in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ SOFTWARE \ PCclient
what should I add to the Inno, so when the uninstall files 'PCclient' can be deleted .. thanks